# Polynomial regresssion with limited sample points

Tags: optimization, experimental-mathematics

Is this solvable and if not, then why not?

Let's say we are given a model that looks as follows:

$y=x+ax^3+bx^5+cx^7+dx^9+\mathcal{N}(0,σ_1^2)$

Given n free choices for the input variable $x$ how can we determine which $x$'s we should choose to get the optimal approximation of the unknown coefficients $a,b,c,d$. The range for $x$ is $(0,t)$ which can of course be scaled to $(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: What do you call "the optimal approximation" ?

Comment: Good question. Maybe you can help me define it more precisely. The more basic problems goes like this. If we try to determine the line y = a + xb + N using 2 points, in order to get the most precise results we place the two points on the furthest and opposite ends of the line, x= 0, x =1. If we place both points really close to one another because of the noise we could get many diferrent lines and in this scenario our new a',b' coefficients would not be as "optimal" as they would be if the points were on the opposite ends.

Comment: I guess the optimal coefficients a',b' would minimize the distance of new sample data from the line y = a' + xb'.